# Rails HTTParty Getting Timeout::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have an API centric application (/api/v1/users) it simply return all users restfully with JSON format.

My problem is, if I call that route on the controller, it returns "Timeout::Error"
What is the problem?

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  def index
    return HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users').body
  end
end
```

**Update**

- users_controller.rb (/api/v1/users)
- application_controller.rb

https://gist.github.com/4359591

**Logs**

http://pastie.org/5565618

Comment: Can you show the controller's method that is responsible for returning the JSON?

Comment: @JiříPospíšil updated my question with more information

Comment: Can you share the logs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an API end-point, at `/api/v1/users`, and your `BaseController#index` is calling that method?

If that is correct, inside the same rails process, and you are testing in development mode (as I can tell from your url), then you only have a single process running, which can only handle a single request at once. So if you start a request to `BaseController#index`, it will start another request to your own test-server, which is busy, and it will just wait until it times out.

If you want to test your API, I would look at a client tool like e.g. [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

HTH.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. So tested my API with Postman extension and also with rails's console everything just works. How can I use multi processes for using in same application?

Comment: While this could be possible, if you install apache/nginx and user passenger for instance, it is a lot of overhead. I do not understand why you would want to do that? It is a scenario heading for troubles. Because each single request will take up two requests of your server. Why not just call the code directly?

Comment: Because I'm building a web/mobile hybrid application, two of them sharing same API

Comment: its not working on webrick/unicorn/thin servers, so running application on passenger/nginx module solved the problem, thanks.