# net/http rails issue works only in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, net-http

in ruby on rails console 'net/http' works, but in controller it doesn't and gives timeout error.

```
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/api_json.json')
json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're using default Webrick server, that serves one request a time. So, from console it works fine, but fails when you try to call it from controller (when the Webrick worker is already busy).

You can try to setup and run another server like unicorn or thin, or run two Webrick instances on different ports:

```
rails server
rails server -p 3001
```

and go to localhost:3001

Answer (score 0):

@dimuch's solution might have solved your issue, but it might help someone facing similar situation. I will explain the issue, and the solution in detail (extension of @dimuch's solution).

Issue:

You might have a controller like some:"/test_controller/test_method", and you might want to call a method in a controller, like /api/v1/some_test_api, and facing error like Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60004.4ms
[27580c5c46770812c550188346c2dd3e] [127.0.0.1] [/xauth_test/sanity_oauth_login]
Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error):

Solution:

As said by @dimuch, "
Most likely you're using default Webrick server, that serves one request a time.....". 1. You need to run the application on different ports, like
rails s -p 3000, and rails s -p 3001, then make the request from 3001.
If you face an issue like "A server is already running. Check /tmp/pids/server.pid. Exiting", then try running rails s -p 3001 -P PROCESS_ID.
2. Use other server's like Unicorn, or Puma.

Note: If you want it for just testing purpose in local, then I would suggest to go with the first solution, which is easy and simple. I am sorry for poor English, and I found most of solutions from other stack overflow pages, and websites, which I am attaching (links for refs) below, and sorry if I missed some one or some thing to refer. Hope this helps someone.

Refs:
For running multiple instances:

[Running multiple instances of Rails Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928680/running-multiple-instances-of-rails-server)

Similar errors and way they are handled:

[Rails HTTParty Getting Timeout::Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004130/rails-httparty-getting-timeouterror?rq=1)

[Faraday timeout error with omniauth (custom strategy)/doorkeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857182/faraday-timeout-error-with-omniauth-custom-strategy-doorkeeper)

[Strange Timeout::Error with render_to_string and HTTParty in Controller Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764175/strange-timeouterror-with-render-to-string-and-httparty-in-controller-action)

Configuring Unicorn &Puma:

http://vladigleba.com/blog/2014/03/21/deploying-rails-apps-part-3-configuring-unicorn/

https://github.com/puma/puma